# Unable To Create Column Using Map Lambda Function - USZIPCODE Module

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am attempting to extract latitude and longitude values from a pandas dataframe column which contains zip codes using lambda function. I found an accepted solution at the link below, but it does not work when I tried it.

[Fast loop through using Pandas - uszipcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66057024/fast-loop-through-using-pandas-uszipcode)

Here is my code:

`df_small['lat1'] = df_small['rep-zip'].map(lambda x: search.by_zipcode(x).lat)`

And the error I am receiving:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lat'

Comment: What would make `search.by_zipcode(x)` return `None`? Is there documentation that you could check?

Comment: It works when I enter a single value from that column. Not sure why it doesn't work inside the map function.
`test = df_small['rep-zip'][0]
zip1 = search.by_zipcode(test)
lat1 = zip1.lat
lat1`
33.1

Comment: It appears that at least one `None` object is being returned by a call to `search.by_zipcode(x)`  `None` objects do not have a `lat` attribute. Are there any missing values in `df_small['rep-zip']`?

Comment: Wow ....Thank you!  There are no missing values, but I found one zip code that had a typo where two of the digits were out of order.